# Rails order greek characters first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a list of names in my DB and I need to sort them alphabetically. However, I need to show the greek letters first, and then the latin ones. For example, I have:

```
[Jale, Βήτα, Άλφα, Ben]
```

and I need to order it like this:

```
[Άλφα, Βήτα, Ben, Jale]
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Comment: As far as I understand you a automatic order is not working? so maybe you can seperate/ sort/split origin arry into two arrays by latin & greek, and then sort inside these two arrays automatically and afterwards putting them together again?

Comment: The automatic order by default shows latin first and then greek letters. What you suggested sounds good

Comment: question: the automatic order does its job right insinde each letters? I mean, the greek ones are at the end but inside the greek ones everything is right? Then I suggest to sort automatic, go through sorted array, take alle with first greek letter and afterwards and take this for new array at beginning and put latin stuff afterwards

Comment: That's what I'd like to do, however my skills are not that high :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to solve these problems by playing around in irb. Here's one way you could go about finding this solution. First, we'll define our test array:

```
>> names = %w{Jale Βήτα Άλφα Ben}
=> ["Jale", "Βήτα", "Άλφα", "Ben"]
```

To solve this, let's first transform the array into 2-tuples which contain a flag indicating whether the name is greek or not, and then the name itself. We want the flag to be sortable, so we'll first find a regex match for latin-only characters, and coerce it to be a string.

```
>> names.map{|name| [(name =~ /^\w+$/).to_s, name]}
=> [["0", "Jale"], ["", "Βήτα"], ["", "Άλφα"], ["0", "Ben"]]
```

Then we'll sort the 2-tuples:

```
>> names.map{|name| [(name =~ /^\w+$/).to_s, name]}.sort
=> [["", "Άλφα"], ["", "Βήτα"], ["0", "Ben"], ["0", "Jale"]]
```

We now have a sort order where we have first the greek names, then the latin names. We can shorten this into our solution:

```
>> names.sort_by{|name| [(name =~ /^\w+$/).to_s, name]}
=> ["Άλφα", "Βήτα", "Ben", "Jale"]
```

Comment: That's great Peter. Like I said I'm not that skilled though and I have my names in a collection called @names. How can I apply that?

Comment: `@names.map(&:name).sort_by{...`

Answer (score 0):

I gave one solution above. Another approach is to partition the names into greek and latin, then sort within those groups, then flatten the two arrays into one:

```
>> names.partition{|name| name !~ /^\w+$/}.map(&:sort).flatten
=> ["Άλφα", "Βήτα", "Ben", "Jale"]
```

This might be a little more elegant and understandable than my other solution, but it is less flexible. Note that `name !~ /\w+$` will return something like `true` if the name has non-latin characters, ie, is greek.